# Calling function of derived class in std::thread constructor end up calling function of base class

Tags: c++

```
class Decoder    {
public:
    virtual void run() {}
    //...
}
```

Now, I have this derived class:

```
class NVDecoder : public Decoder
{
public:
    void run();
```

which is defined as this in the NVDecoder.cpp file

```
void NVDecoder::run()
{
//...
}
```

As the function void of `Decoder` is `virtual`, doing:

```
//Decoder decoder = new NVDecoder();
auto decoder = std::make_shared<NVDecoder>(NVDecoder::NALU,Decoder::H264);
decoder->run();
```

should call the `NVDecoder`'s run function, not the `Decoder`'s one. However, when I start a thread for a generic `Decoder` object, I need to do like this:

```
auto decoderThread = std::make_shared<std::thread>(&Decoder::run, decoder);
```

This calls the `Decoder`'s run function, not the `NVDecoder`'s one. I guess it's because I pass `&Decoder::run`. How do I start a thread that uses the `NVDecoder`'s `run` function without passing `&NVDecoder::run`?

Comment: Classic object slicing: `decoder` is a `Decoder`, not an `NVDecoder`: that one died just after initializing `decoder`. You need references to observe polymorphism, as in `Decoder &&decoder = NVDecoder();`.

Comment: It shouldn't. Here 'Decoder decoder = NVDecoder();' you 've just get a slicing of the derived object. so run will be from base class.
Try to use pointers.
'Decoder* decoder = new NVDecoder();'

Comment: @Roout actually it was supposed to be a shared pointer, I updated the example.

Comment: @Roout in the case of a shared pointer, how sould I pass the object to the thread?

Comment: Aditionally, why I can call the derived's function when using pointers but not when using object instances?

Comment: @Guerlando OCs
Because when you are using pointers to create object you do not perform copy operation on object itself.
Consider example.

Base base = Derived der;
you create derived object first then you call copy constructor which by default will "cut off" all variables and fucntions that are not in Base class. So you end up with object that is of type Base but created from Derived.
Using pointers:

Base * base  = new Derived ();
you create pointer of type Base which points to object of type Derived (containing all infromation from Derived class)